# Use psycopg2 to do loop in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, python-2.7, windows-8.1, psycopg2, postgresql-8.4

I use postgresql 8.4 to route a river network, and I want to use psycopg2 to loop through all data points in my river network.

```
#set up python and postgresql connection
import psycopg2

query = """
    select *
    from driving_distance ($$
        select
            gid as id,
            start_id::int4 as source,
            end_id::int4 as target,
            shape_leng::double precision as cost
        from network
        $$, %s, %s, %s, %s
    )
;"""


conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname = 'routing_template' user = 'postgres' host = 'localhost' password = '****'")
cur = conn.cursor()
while True:
    i = 1
    if i <= 2:
        cur.execute(query, (i, 1000000, False, False))
        i = i + 1
    else:
        break
rs = cur.fetchall()
conn.close()
print rs
```

The code above costs a lot of time to run even though I have set the maximum iterator i equals to 2, and the output is an error message contains garbage,

[image]

I am thinking that if postgresql can accept only one result at one time, so I tried to put this line in my loop,

```
rs(i) = cur.fetchall()
```

and the error message said that this line has bugs,

[image]

I know that I can't write code like **rs(i)**, but I don't know the replacement to validate my assumption.

So should I save one result to a file first then use the next iterator to run the loop, and again and again?

I am working with postgresql 8.4, python 2.7.6 under Windows 8.1 x64.

---

**Update#1**

I can do loop using Clodoaldo Neto's code(thanks), and the result is like this,

```
[(1, 2, 0.0), (2, 2, 4729.33082850235), (3, 19, 4874.27571718902), (4, 3, 7397.215962901), (5, 4, 
6640.31749097187), (6, 7, 10285.3869655786), (7, 7, 14376.1087618696), (8, 5, 15053.164236979), (9, 10, 16243.5973710466), (10, 8, 19307.3024368889), (11, 9, 21654.8669532788), (12, 11, 23522.6224229233), (13, 18, 29706.6964721152), (14, 21, 24034.6792693279), (15, 18, 25408.306370489), (16, 20, 34204.1769580924), (17, 11, 26465.8348728118), (18, 20, 38596.7313209197), (19, 13, 35184.9925532175), (20, 16, 36530.059646027), (21, 15, 35789.4069722436), (22, 15, 38168.1750567026)]
[(1, 2, 4729.33082850235), (2, 2, 0.0), (3, 19, 144.944888686669), (4, 3, 2667.88513439865), (5, 4, 1910.98666246952), (6, 7, 5556.05613707624), (7, 7, 9646.77793336723), (8, 5, 10323.8334084767), (9, 10, 11514.2665425442), (10, 8, 14577.9716083866), (11, 9, 16925.5361247765), (12, 11, 18793.2915944209), (13, 18, 24977.3656436129), (14, 21, 19305.3484408255), (15, 18, 20678.9755419867), (16, 20, 29474.8461295901), (17, 11, 21736.5040443094), (18, 20, 33867.4004924174), (19, 13, 30455.6617247151), (20, 16, 31800.7288175247), (21, 15, 31060.0761437413), (22, 15, 33438.8442282003)]
```

but if I want to get this look of output,

```
(1, 2, 7397.215962901)
(2, 2, 2667.88513439865)
(3, 19, 2522.94024571198)
(4, 3, 0.0)
(5, 4, 4288.98201949483)
(6, 7, 7934.05149410155)
(7, 7, 12024.7732903925)
(8, 5, 12701.828765502)
(9, 10, 13892.2618995696)
(10, 8, 16955.9669654119)
(11, 9, 19303.5314818018)
(12, 11, 21171.2869514462)
(13, 18, 27355.3610006382)
(14, 21, 21683.3437978508)
(15, 18, 23056.970899012)
(16, 20, 31852.8414866154)
(17, 11, 24114.4994013347)
(18, 20, 36245.3958494427)
(19, 13, 32833.6570817404)
(20, 16, 34178.72417455)
(21, 15, 33438.0715007666)
(22, 15, 35816.8395852256)
```

What should I make a little change in the code？

Comment: I can't figure out what your PostgreSQL question is trying to be, but the first thing you need to fix is the infinite loop you coded into python.

Comment: @jjanes thank you for your comment, my sql question in this post relates to proficiency of loop command in sql language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rs = []
while True:
    i = 1
    if i <= 2:
        cur.execute(query, (i, 1000000, False, False))
        rs.extend(cur.fetchall())
        i = i + 1
    else:
        break
conn.close()
print rs
```

If it is just a counter that breaks that loop then

```
rs = []
i = 1
while i <= 2:
    cur.execute(query, (i, 1000000, False, False))
    rs.extend(cur.fetchall())
    i = i + 1
conn.close()
print rs
```

Comment: @Heinz In instead of `append` use `extend` as in my updated answer